# Showing number of slides on the web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wrote a custom slider as shown in this codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqQpjG
I added extra feature which counts total number of slides that are moved. For example, if total slides are 8, then starting value would be like this:
`Slides: 0/8`. When one slide moves, it becomes `Slides: 1/8` and so on. Here is my code:

```
<div>
            <span id="numberSlides">0/0 Offers</span>
        </div>
```

**`JS`**

```
var slide = new slide('.swiper-slide', {
        var totalSlides = 10;
        var newSlide = document.getElementsByClassName('swiper-slide');
        var newValue = newSlide + 1;
        document.getElementById('numberSlides').innerHTML = newValue + "/" + totalSlides + " Slides";
    });
```

But it isn't working. How can I display the number of slides that are moved?
**EDIT:**
My slides are in these `divs`:

```
<div class="swiper-container">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
        </div>
        <!-- Add Pagination -->
        <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this properties

```
  runCallbacksOnInit: true, 
  onInit: function(sw){}, //runs callback in initialization
  onSlideChangeEnd: function(sw){} //runs callback in slide change end
```

Demo

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
  paginationClickable: true,
  nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
  prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
  spaceBetween: 30,
  centeredSlides: true,
  autoplay: 3000,
  autoplayDisableOnInteraction: false,
  runCallbacksOnInit: true,
  onInit: function(sw){
    var offer = document.querySelector('#numberSlides');
    offer.innerHTML = (sw.activeIndex +  1) + '/' + sw.slides.length + 'Offers';
  },
  onSlideChangeEnd: function(sw){
    var offer = document.querySelector('#numberSlides');
    offer.innerHTML = (sw.activeIndex +  1) + '/' + sw.slides.length + 'Offers';
  }
});
```

```css
#numberSlides{
  position: absolute; 
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
}

html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;
  /* Center slide text vertically */
  
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.1.2/js/swiper.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.1.2/css/swiper.css">
<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
  </div>
  <!-- Add Pagination -->
  <div class="swiper-pagination swiper-pagination-clickable"></div>
  <div id="numberSlides">
    0/0 Offers
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I was away from my system. But I didn't downvote your code. I tried your code in my custom slider and it didn't work.

Comment: You have typo `<script src="js/swiper.min.css"></script>`, it must be `<script src="js/swiper.min.js"></script>` Can you make Codepen demo?

Comment: Yeah, fixed it. Thank you. I'm accepting your answer and closing down this question :)

Comment: What was the reason of failure?

Comment: I fixed that typo, added css for `numberSlides`. It fixed everything

Comment: But I'd love to see counts at `top center` rather than in `bottom left`.

Comment: just modify style of __#numberSlides__, note it's `div`. Further readings can be found [here](https://css-tricks.com/quick-css-trick-how-to-center-an-object-exactly-in-the-center/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87861/discussion-between-ajay-kulkarni-and-evc).

Answer (score 3):

### 100% swiper API solution (Works with loop true -or- false & more than one swiper on a page).

If you want to use your own elements.

Instead of using your own Logic/Calculation `total-slides` - **clean solution** is to get the total number of slides [beforeInit](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#event-beforeInit) (Before dupluaction of slides).

#### a.Current slide

Use `realIndex + 1` (Beacuse this is **zero base index** => 0 == first slide) and upadte the counter on [slideChange](https://swiperjs.com/api/#events) by [innerHTML](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp) property.

```
slideChange: function(){
   var currentSlide = this.realIndex + 1;
   document.querySelector('.current-slide').innerHTML = currentSlide;
},
```

#### b. Total slides

`beforeInit` - Event will be fired right before initialization (Before swiper duplicate slides)
https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#event-beforeInit

[swiper.wrapperEl](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#prop-swiper-wrapperEl) - vanilla HTMLElementelement with slider wrapper HTML element.

Than [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) (Vanilla js) `this`(swiper.wrapperEl) `swiper-slide` **length** property.

```
on: {
  beforeInit: function () {
    let numOfSlides = this.wrapperEl.querySelectorAll(".swiper-slide").length;
    console.log(numOfSlides);
}
```

#### snippet

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    loop: true,
    pagination: {
      el: '.swiper-pagination',
    },
    /* events */
    on: {
      slideChange: function(){
        var currentSlide = this.realIndex + 1;
        console.log("currentSlide is:" + currentSlide);
        document.querySelector('.current-slide').innerHTML = currentSlide;
      },
      beforeInit: function(){
      let numOfSlides = this.wrapperEl.querySelectorAll(".swiper-slide").length;
      document.querySelector('.total-slides').innerHTML = numOfSlides;
      }
    }
  });
```

```css
html, body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.counter{
  border: 3px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}
strong{
  color: red;
  font-size: 32px;
}
.swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}


    on: {
      beforeInit: function () {
        let numOfSlides = this.wrapperEl.querySelectorAll(".swiper-slide").length;
        console.log(numOfSlides);
      },
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper@6.3.4/swiper-bundle.min.css">
  
<p class="counter">
<strong class="current-slide">current-slide</strong>
of
<strong class="total-slides">Total</strong>
<p>
  
<!-- Swiper -->
<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
  </div>
  <!-- Add Pagination -->
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>

  
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@6.3.4/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
```

#### type: fraction

https://swiperjs.com/api/#pagination

Swiper API `type: fraction` pagination:

```
pagination: {
  el: '.swiper-pagination',
  type: "fraction"
},
```

And `renderFraction` for example:

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  //...
  renderFraction: function (currentClass, totalClass) {
      return '<span class="' + currentClass + '"></span>' +
              ' of ' +
              '<span class="' + totalClass + '"></span>';
  }
});
```